# Hover element1 + element2 when hoving element1

Tags: html, css, wordpress

My code look like:

```
<html>
<h3>product4</h3>
<span class="price"><del></del> <ins><span class="amount">£100</span></ins></span>
</html>
```

Css looks like:

```
ul.products li.product h3 {
text-decoration:none;
color:transparent;
}

ul.products li.product a:hover h3 {
color:#ffffff;
}

.price ins {
text-decoration:none;
color:transparent;
}

.price ins :hover{
text-decoration:none;
color:#ffffff;
}
```

I want to hear how I can make a code, so when I hover over the h3 both the h3 and the price will be #fffff. 
And then when I hover the price both the price and the h3 will be #fffff

I know I could put both into one parent, but this is not possible because I use WooCommerce and this would be too advanced.

You can watch the problem live on: http://oliver.kaspertoxvig.dk/ (by moving your cursor to one of the four images)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [adjacent sibling selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors) like so:

```
h3:hover, h3:hover + .price{color:#FFF;}
```

See it in action: http://jsfiddle.net/RL43N/

unfortunately, it's not possible with pure CSS to allow the user hover over the `.price` to highlight the `h3`. You would need some JavaScript to do this.

Comment: Actually, it would be possible if the OP just wants something simple like this http://jsfiddle.net/JoshC/RL43N/1/

Comment: Obviously that would be the handiest thing to do but he mentions that he cannot change the markup

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest, with your posted code:

```
h3:hover,
h3:hover + span.price {
    color: #fff;
}
```

[Simple demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/732XM/).

This uses the adjacent-sibling (`+`) combinator to select the next sibling (if it matches the `span.price` selector) of the element matched by `h3:hover` selector.

References:

- [Adjacent-sibling (`+`) combinator](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#adjacent-sibling-combinators).